# How to get average of a column inside a time era?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to get the average of a column (which I will set in the input of my function) during a precise era :
In my case the date is the index, so I can get the week with `index.week`.
Then I would like to compute some basic statistics each `2` weeks for instances

So I will need to "slice" the dataframe every `2` weeks and then compute. It can destroy the part of the dataframe already computed, but what's still in the dataframe mustn't be erase.

My first guess was to parse the data with a row iterator then compare it :

```
# get the week num. of the first row
start_week =  temp.data.index.week[0]

# temp.data is my data frame
for index, row in temp.data.iterrows():
    while index.week < start_week + 2:
        print index.week
```

but it's really slow so shouldn't be the proper way

Comment: While I will not deny that your iterative way is inefficient - why do you use `while` instead of `if`?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please note that your question is not very specific and is difficult to supply you with exactly what you want. Optimally, you would supply code to recreate your dataset and also post the expected outcome. I'll post regarding two parts: (i) Working with dataframes sliced using time-specific functions and (ii) Applying statistical functions using rolling window operations.

**Working with Dataframes and time indices**

The question is not *how to get the mean of x*, because you know how to do that (`x.mean()`). The question is, how to get `x`: How do you select elements of a dataframe which satisfy certain conditions on their timestamp? I will use a series generated [by the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) which I found after googling for one minute:

```
In[13]: ts
Out[13]: 
2011-01-31    0.356701
2011-02-28   -0.814078
2011-03-31    1.382372
2011-04-29    0.604897
2011-05-31    1.415689
2011-06-30   -0.237188
2011-07-29   -0.197657
2011-08-31   -0.935760
2011-09-30    2.060165
2011-10-31    0.618824
2011-11-30    1.670747
2011-12-30   -1.690927
```

Then, you can select some time series based on index weeks using

```
ts[(ts.index.week > 3) & (ts.index.week < 10)]
```

And specifically, if you want to get the mean of this series, you can do

```
ts[(ts.index.week > 3) & (ts.index.week < 10)].mean()
```

If you work with a dataframe, you might want to select the column first:

```
df[(df.index.week > 3) & (df.index.week < 10)]['someColumn'].mean()
```

**Rolling window operations**

Now, if you want to operate rolling statistics onto a time series indexed pandas object, have a look at [this part of the manual](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments).

Given that I have a monthly time series, say I want the mean for 3 months, I'd do:

```
rolling_mean(ts, window=3)
Out[25]: 
2011-01-31         NaN
2011-02-28         NaN
2011-03-31    0.308331
2011-04-29    0.391064
2011-05-31    1.134319
2011-06-30    0.594466
2011-07-29    0.326948
2011-08-31   -0.456868
2011-09-30    0.308916
2011-10-31    0.581076
2011-11-30    1.449912
2011-12-30    0.199548
```

Comment: maybe show an example of ``resample('2W',how='mean')`` which i think is relevant here